# Three spheres intersection (trilateration) with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, computational-geometry

Is there a way to get a solution to three spheres intersection (trilateration) with SymPy? `sympy.geometry` doesn't have a sphere object, so a direct approach is not feasible. Can SymPy solve a system of non-linear equations as shown at [Trilateration and the Intersection of Three Spheres](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TrilaterationAndTheIntersectionOfThreeSpheres/)?

Comment: By subtraction, you turn two sphere equations to a plane equation (the plane that contains their intersection). Taking two pairs, you obtain a straight line. Intersecting with two arbitrary other planes, you get two points that let you define the parametric equation of the line. And finally, a univariate quadratic equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. There are different ways but e.g.:

```
In [21]: x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z', real=True)

In [22]: eq1 = (x-1)**2 + (y-2)**2 + (z-3)**2 - 1

In [23]: eq2 = (x-1)**2 + (y-S(5)/2)**2 + (z-3)**2 - 1

In [24]: eq3 = (x-S.Half)**2 + (y-S(5)/2)**2 + (z-3)**2 - 1

In [25]: solve([eq1, eq2, eq3], [x, y, z])
Out[25]: 
⎡⎛              √14⎞  ⎛          √14    ⎞⎤
⎢⎜3/4, 9/4, 3 - ───⎟, ⎜3/4, 9/4, ─── + 3⎟⎥
⎣⎝               4 ⎠  ⎝           4     ⎠⎦
```

Answer (score 2):

This post is in case someone benefits from what I have posted below.

One can actually solve this problem somewhat more geometrically, rather than solving systems of quadratic equations. The approach below can handle three spheres given as centers and radii or as spheres represented by three quadratic equations. Even if the three spheres are given as three quadratic equations of three variables, one can extract the coefficients and obtain the radii and the coordinates of the centers of the three spheres. Then, the two intersection points can be found geometrically, by applying the law of cosine a few times.

```
def norm_2(v):
    return v.dot(v)
def norm(v):
    return np.sqrt(norm_2(v))

def extract_center_and_radius(sphere_coefficients):
    '''
    sphere_equation should be 
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + a1*x + a2*y + a3*z + a4 = 0
    so sphere equation should be parametrized
    as a list of 4 coefficients
    [a1, a2, a3, a4]
    '''
    a = np.array(sphere_coefficients)
    center = - a[0:3] / 2
    radius = np.sqrt(center.dot(center) - a[3])
    return center, radius

def intersecton_3_spheres(sphere1, sphere2, sphere3):
    '''
    spherei = (center, radius) is a tuple or a list, 
    with first entry an np.array representing
    the coordinates of the center, 
    the second being the radius
    '''
    A, rA = sphere1
    B, rB = sphere2
    C, rC = sphere3
    AB = B-A
    AC = C-A
    l_AB = norm(AB)
    l_AC = norm(AC)
    l_BC = norm(C-B)
    x2 = (l_AB**2 + l_AC**2 - l_BC**2) / (2 * l_AB)
    y2 = np.sqrt(l_AC**2 - x2**2)
    x3 = (l_AB**2 + rA**2 - rB**2) / (2*l_AB)
    y3 = (l_AC**2 + rA**2 - rC**2) / 2
    y3 = (y3 - x2*x3) / y2
    z3 = np.sqrt(rA**2 - x3**2 - y3**2)
    n = np.cross(AB, AC)
    n = n / norm(n)
    AB = AB / l_AB
    b = np.cross(n, AB)
    return A + x3*AB + y3*b + z3*n, A + x3*AB + y3*b - z3*n

def intersecton_of_3_spheres(sphere1, sphere2, sphere3):
    '''
    the input is three lists of 4 coefficients each
    e.g. [a1, a2, a3, a4] which describe the coefficients 
    of three sphere equations 
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + a1*x + a2*y + a3*z + a4 = 0    
    '''
    center_radius_1 = extract_center_and_radius(sphere1)
    center_radius_2 = extract_center_and_radius(sphere2)
    center_radius_3 = extract_center_and_radius(sphere3)
    return intersecton_3_spheres(center_radius_1, center_radius_2, center_radius_3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The results passed a few tests. For the reference, on Intel i5-9600K CPU and Python 3.8.10, your code is 7.9K times faster than a SymPy equivalent.

Comment: @PaulJurczak I am glad it helps. Cheers!

Comment: BTW, `norm` is available in Numpy as `numpy.linalg.norm`.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Yeah, I know. But I tend to use it more when there is some sort of vectorization (e.g. norms of row or column or row-vectors in a matrix), rather than simple norm. I was planning initially to use the norm squared whenever applicable to avoid as much as possible the square root calculation, but then I abandoned this intention.