# Three spheres intersection (trilateration) with SymPy[2]

Tags: sympy

I can value.I want variable

①Calculation of the intersection of two circles

②Calculation of intersections of three spheres(value)

➂Calculation of intersections of three spheres(variable)

```
from sympy import *
x  ,y   = symbols('x  ,y  ',real=True)
xm1,ym1 = symbols('xm1,ym1',real=True)
xm2,ym2 = symbols('xm2,ym2',real=True)
rm1,rm2 = symbols('rm1,rm2',real=True,positive=True)
eq1 = (x-xm1)**2 + (y-ym1)**2 - rm1**2
eq2 = (x-xm2)**2 + (y-ym2)**2 - rm2**2
ans=solve([eq1, eq2], [x, y])
mySubs={xm1:0.0,ym1:0.0,rm1:1.0,xm2:1.0,ym2:0.0,rm2:1.0}
print("#line10#",ans[0][0],ans[0][1])
print("#line11#",ans[0][0].subs(mySubs),ans[0][1].subs(mySubs))

from sympy import *
x  ,y  ,z   = symbols('x  ,y  ,z  ',real=True)
xm1,ym1,zm1 = symbols('xm1,ym1,zm1',real=True)
xm2,ym2,zm2 = symbols('xm2,ym2,zm2',real=True)
xm3,ym3,zm3 = symbols('xm3,ym3,zm3',real=True)
rm1,rm2,rm3 = symbols('rm1,rm2,rm3',real=True,positive=True)
xm1,ym1,zm1,rm1=0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
xm2,ym2,zm2,rm2=1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
xm3,ym3,zm3,rm3=0.5,0.5*sqrt(3.0),0.0,1.0
eq1 = (x-xm1)**2 + (y-ym1)**2 + (z-zm1)**2 - rm1**2
eq2 = (x-xm2)**2 + (y-ym2)**2 + (z-zm2)**2 - rm2**2
eq3 = (x-xm3)**2 + (y-ym3)**2 + (z-zm3)**2 - rm3**2
print("#line24#",solve([eq1, eq2, eq3], [x, y, z])[0])

from sympy import *
x  ,y  ,z   = symbols('x  ,y  ,z  ',real=True)
xm1,ym1,zm1 = symbols('xm1,ym1,zm1',real=True)
xm2,ym2,zm2 = symbols('xm2,ym2,zm2',real=True)
xm3,ym3,zm3 = symbols('xm3,ym3,zm3',real=True)
rm1,rm2,rm3 = symbols('rm1,rm2,rm3',real=True,positive=True)
eq1 = (x-xm1)**2 + (y-ym1)**2 + (z-zm1)**2 - rm1**2
eq2 = (x-xm2)**2 + (y-ym2)**2 + (z-zm2)**2 - rm2**2
eq3 = (x-xm3)**2 + (y-ym3)**2 + (z-zm3)**2 - rm3**2
print("#line34#",solve([eq1, eq2, eq3], [x, y, z])[0])
#line10#  <omit>
#line11# 0.500000000000000 0.866025403784439
#line24# (0.500000000000000, 0.288675134594813, -0.816496580927726)
```

(ref)

[Three spheres intersection (trilateration) with SymPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69987186/three-spheres-intersection-trilateration-with-sympy)

Comment: What is your specific question? Are you hoping for a nice mathematical formula? That doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic simplification of Points makes this slow, but it's probably a good idea to use `cse` on the symbolic expression anyway. This modification of the post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70307902/1089161) to run in pure SymPy will calculate the two intersection points symbolically:

```
def norm_2(v):
    from sympy import Add
    return Add(*[i**2 for i in v])

def norm(v):
    from sympy import sqrt
    return sqrt(norm_2(v))

def cross(a, b):
    from sympy import Matrix
    return Matrix(a).cross(Matrix(b))

def extract_center_and_radius(sphere_coefficients):
    '''
    sphere_equation should be 
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + a1*x + a2*y + a3*z + a4 = 0
    so sphere equation should be parametrized
    as a list of 4 coefficients
    [a1, a2, a3, a4]
    '''
    from sympy import Point, sqrt
    a = sphere_coefficients
    center = Point([i/2 for i in a[:3]])
    radius = sqrt(center.dot(center) - a[3])
    return center, radius

def intersection_3_spheres(sphere1, sphere2, sphere3):
    '''
    spherei = (center, radius) is a tuple or a list, 
    with first entry an np.array representing
    the coordinates of the center, 
    the second being the radius
    '''
    from sympy import sqrt, Point, cse
    A, rA = sphere1
    B, rB = sphere2
    C, rC = sphere3
    AB = B-A
    AC = C-A
    l_AB = norm(AB)
    l_AC = norm(AC)
    l_BC = norm(C-B)
    x2 = (l_AB**2 + l_AC**2 - l_BC**2) / (2 * l_AB)
    y2 = sqrt(l_AC**2 - x2**2)
    x3 = (l_AB**2 + rA**2 - rB**2) / (2*l_AB)
    y3 = (l_AC**2 + rA**2 - rC**2) / 2
    y3 = (y3 - x2*x3) / y2
    z3 = sqrt(rA**2 - x3**2 - y3**2)
    n = cross(AB, AC)
    m = norm(n)
    n = Point([i/m for i in n])
    AB = AB / l_AB
    b = cross(n, AB)
    r, e = cse((A, AB, x3, y3, z3, b, n))
    A, AB, x3, y3, z3, b, n = e
    return r, A + x3*AB + y3*b, z3*n


def sphere_coefficients(eq):
    e = eq.expand()
    x, y, z = [i for i in ordered(eq.free_symbols) if i.name in ['x', 'y', 'z']]
    assert all(e.coeff(i**2) == 1 for i in (x, y, z))
    return (e.coeff(x), e.coeff(y), e.coeff(z), e.xreplace({x:0,y:0,z:0}))


def intersection_of_3_spheres(sphere1, sphere2, sphere3):
    """
    the input is three lists of 4 coefficients each
    e.g. [a1, a2, a3, a4] which describe the coefficients 
    of three sphere equations 
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + a1*x + a2*y + a3*z + a4 = 0
    or the actual equation.

    output is (r, p, d) where `r` is a list of common patterns
    extracted from the intersection points which are `p + d` and
    `p - d`

    Examples
    ========

    >>> from sympy import symbols

    A concrete example:

    >>> x  ,y  ,z   = symbols('x  ,y  ,z  ',real=True)
    >>> xm1,ym1,zm1 = symbols('xm1,ym1,zm1',real=True)
    >>> xm2,ym2,zm2 = symbols('xm2,ym2,zm2',real=True)
    >>> xm3,ym3,zm3 = symbols('xm3,ym3,zm3',real=True)
    >>> rm1,rm2,rm3 = symbols('rm1,rm2,rm3',real=True,positive=True)
    >>> xm1,ym1,zm1,rm1=0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
    >>> xm2,ym2,zm2,rm2=1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
    >>> xm3,ym3,zm3,rm3=0.5,0.5*sqrt(3.0),0.0,1.0
    >>> eq1 = (x-xm1)**2 + (y-ym1)**2 + (z-zm1)**2 - rm1**2
    >>> eq2 = (x-xm2)**2 + (y-ym2)**2 + (z-zm2)**2 - rm2**2
    >>> eq3 = (x-xm3)**2 + (y-ym3)**2 + (z-zm3)**2 - rm3**2
    >>> intersection_of_3_spheres(eq1, eq2, eq3)
    ([], Point3D(-0.500000000000000, -0.288675134594813, 0),
    Point3D(0, 0, 0.816496580927726))

    """
    from sympy.utilities.iterables import iterable
    coeffs = [sphere_coefficients(i) if not iterable(i)
        else i for i in (sphere1, sphere2, sphere3)]
    cr = [extract_center_and_radius(i) for i in coeffs]
    return intersection_3_spheres(*cr)
```

Getting the output once allows us to write the general answer with cse-identified patterns extracted for efficient calculation. And we can use that to calculate a numeric or symbolic answers:

```
def trilateration(pdict):
    """return the Coordinates of the intersection points for 3
    spHeRes gIven a dictionary with STring keys "a"-"l" MApped
    to valueS defIning the 3 SpHEREs:

    sphere1 = (x - a)**2 + (y - b)**2 + (z - c)**2 - d**2
    sphere2 = (x - e)**2 + (y - f)**2 + (z - g)**2 - h**2
    sphere3 = (x - i)**2 + (y - j)**2 + (z - k)**2 - l**2


    Examples
    ========

    A concrete example:

    >>> from math import sqrt
    >>> [[i.n(2) for i in j] for j in trilateration(
    ...     {'d':1, 'h':1, 'e':1, 'i':.5, 'j': .5*sqrt(3), 'l':1})]
    [[-0.50, -0.19, 0.84], [-0.50, -0.19, -0.84]]

    A symbolic example with concrete verification:

    >>> from sympy import sqrt, var, count_ops, reshape, flatten, Tuple
    >>> s = 'abcdefghijkl'
    >>> pts = trilateration(dict(zip(s, var(list(s)))))

    The symbolic form of intersection coordinates is large:

    >>> count_ops(pts)
    2910

    The symbolic form reduces to the conrete example with numeric input:

    >>> reps = dict(zip(var('a:l'), [0]*12))
    >>> reps.update({d:1,h:1,e:1,l:1,i:S.Half,j:sqrt(3)/2})
    >>> reshape(Tuple(*flatten(pts)).xreplace(reps),(3,))[0]
    [(-1/2, -sqrt(7)/14, sqrt(35)/7), (-1/2, -sqrt(7)/14, -sqrt(35)/7)]
    >>> [[i.n(2) for i in j] for j in _]
    [[-0.50, -0.19, 0.84], [-0.50, -0.19, -0.84]]
    """
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l=[S(pdict.get(x, 0)) for x in 'abcdefghijkl']
    x0 = a - e
    x1 = b - f
    x2 = c - g
    x3 = x0**2 + x1**2 + x2**2
    x4 = 1/sqrt(x3)
    x5 = x0*x4
    x6 = x1*x4
    x7 = x2*x4
    x8 = d**2
    x9 = -h**2 + x3 + x8
    x10 = -i
    x11 = -j
    x12 = -k
    x13 = a + x10
    x14 = x13**2
    x15 = b + x11
    x16 = x15**2
    x17 = c + x12
    x18 = x17**2
    x19 = x14 + x16 + x18
    x20 = x19 + x3 - (e + x10**2 - (f + x11)**2 - (g + x12)**2)
    x21 = 1/(4*x3)
    x22 = x19 - x20**2*x21
    x23 = -l**2/2 + x14/2 + x16/2 + x18/2 - x20*x21*x9 + x8/2
    x24 = x0*x15 - x1*x13
    x25 = -x0*x17 + x13*x2
    x26 = x1*x17 - x15*x2
    x27 = 1/sqrt(x24**2 + x25**2 + x26**2)
    x28 = x24*x27
    x29 = x26*x27
    x30 = x25*x27
    p = ((sqrt(x22)*(-2*a + x4*x5*x9)/2 + x23*(x2*x25*x27*x4 - x28*x6))/sqrt(x22),
        (sqrt(x22)*(-2*b + x4*x6*x9)/2 + x23*(x28*x5 - x29*x7))/sqrt(x22),
        (sqrt(x22)*(-2*c + x4*x7*x9)/2 + x23*(x1*x26*x27*x4 - x30*x5))/sqrt(x22))
    d = (x29*sqrt(-x21*x9**2 + x8 - x23**2/x22),
        x30*sqrt(-x21*x9**2 + x8 - x23**2/x22),
        x28*sqrt(-x21*x9**2 + x8 - x23**2/x22))
    return [i + j for i, j in zip(p, d)], [i - j for i, j in zip(p, d)]
```